# CSS scroll overflow of checkboxes in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I use several lists of checkboxes in a two-column layout which are within a container to allow scrolling and constrain the list size.

Now, sometimes the checkboxes (without their labels) are displayed even though they are outside of the visible portion of the scrolling div. If I remove the column option the visual glitch dissapears. The snippet below illustrates the issue, I encouter this using chrome 75.0.3770.100. Firefox does not produce the problem. IE and Edge appear to be fine as well.

Is this a known bug with a known workaround or am I doing something wrong?

Also, screenshot for people with browsers which do not create the problem:
[image: checkbox rendered outside of visible scroll area]

```css
div.parent{
  column-count: 2;
}
div.list{
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

label{
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input{
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="list">
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry a text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry b text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry c text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry d text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry e text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry f text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry g text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry h text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry i text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry j text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry k text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry l text long enough to overflow</label>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry a text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry b text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry c text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry d text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry e text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry f text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry g text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry h text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry i text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry j text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry k text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry l text long enough to overflow</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The cause is `position: relative;` on checkbox element, why do you need it?

Comment: Im using google chrome and it looks fine to me

Comment: @Morpheus Purely aesthetics: To me, the default position of checkboxes looks always wrong. You're right that it resolves the issue though. But still I'd consider this a bug or is this somehow by design?

Comment: The cause is `position: relative`. I think you need it to align middle, just remove it and add the magic line: `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: @Ivan That is a much better alternative, I was not aware of that option. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`column-count: 2;` CSS not working properly, change with `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
div.parent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
div.parent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div.list{
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

label{
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input{
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="list">
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry a text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry b text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry c text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry d text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry e text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry f text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry g text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry h text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry i text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry j text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry k text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry l text long enough to overflow</label>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry a text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry b text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry c text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry d text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry e text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry f text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry g text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry h text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry i text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry j text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry k text long enough to overflow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">entry l text long enough to overflow</label>
  </div>
</div>
```